# IPad Core Data Leak?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ipad, core-data

Im using XCode 3.2.3 and have created an app using the SplitView template with Core Data.
When i run the default app on the device (3.2) in debug mode with instruments running
i am seeing a leak.
When the default app has no items added to the table view within the split view there is no leak.
But after adding items and running the app a leak is reported.

Responsible Frames are ....

NSPushAutoreleasePool
+[NSThread currentThread]
WTF:initializeMainThreadPlatform()
WTF:initializeMainThreadPlatform()
WTF:initializeMainThreadPlatform()

I beleive the issue happens when fetchedResultsController is called

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

/*
 Set up the fetched results controller.
 */
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

[aFetchedResultsController release];
[fetchRequest release];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

return fetchedResultsController;
```

}

Any advice or pointers appreciated.

Comment: Maybe some one could fire up the splitview template with coredata and see if they get the same results with Instruments ?